# Fetch using React Native and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

Attempting to make a call to an API to get some data and store it in my components state. I am using `useEffect` with a `[]` dependency to fire only once. The `setEntries` line causes Expo to panic and crash on iOS. If I comment that out, I can log and see that the API is returning what I would expect. I am wondering if some kind of infinite loop is being kicked off by calling `setEntries` but I do not see that happening when I log to the console.

I have also tested adding `isLoading`, `entries` and `isError` to the dependency array to no avail.

Relevant code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../../../styles';
import Card from '../../shared/components/card';
import { Entry } from '../../shared/models/Entry';
import { REQUEST } from '../../shared/services/networking';

export const EntryList = () => {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
   fetch(url)
      .then((result) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (result.ok) {
          return result.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error(result.status.toString());
        }
      })
      .then((entries) => {
        if (entries) {
          setEntries(entries.data.sort((a: Entry, b: Entry) => Date.parse(b.createdAt) - Date.parse(a.createdAt)));
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
        setIsError(e);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={globalStyles.container}>
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        {isError && <Text>Sorry, we encountered an error.</Text>}
        {isLoading && <Text>Loading...</Text>}
        {entries && !isLoading ? (
          entries.map((entry, i) => <Card entry={entry} key={`entry-${i}`} />)
        ) : (
          <Text>No entries found. Tell us about your day :)</Text>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

**EDIT: Some additional detail that is further complicating this issue. When I run this code on my MacBook, Expo works properly. When I run the same code on my Linux desktop (Elementary OS), I get the behavior described above. Because of this, I have opened an issue with Expo here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11352**

Comment: mabe your sort function is crashing?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: That’s the thing, there is no error just Expo freezes on me and eventually crashes. Not sure what I’m doing wrong...

Comment: Sort function is not crashing as the log, if I comment out the `setEntries`, shows a sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

I think issue might be because you have same name `entries` in your `state` and request response in `.then((entries) => {...})`. Try to change name in your response like response or something like

```
.then((response) => {
    if (response) {
       setEntries(response.data.sort((a: Entry, b: Entry) => Date.parse(b.createdAt) - Date.parse(a.createdAt)));
    }
})
```

Comment: Excellent catch! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Really strange, this worked properly when developing on my Macbook. I then continued development on my Linux computer and saw the same original error I had, despite your change.